# Why so many takes of the corridor scene for an absurd result?

Tags: oldboy

Dae-su in the corridor scene in Oldboy is hopeless

- missing hits many times
- bad start - lets them get organised rather than surprising them by
  throwing himself and the hurt man at them
- bad tactics- gets enemies on both sides, throws away his claw
  hammers...

He shouldn't have stand a chance against so many enemies, so they must be the worst enemies ever to fail. Is it a point to show that it's only a movie or they just couldn't do anything more credible?

Answer (score 2):

A certain degree of cinematic liberty is taken while shooting stunt scenes and Oldboy's famous corridor scene was no exception. But I don't think the director wanted to convey that. I believe it's more to establish Dae-su's doggedness.

Dae-su has been training hard for 15 years and you can see he gets used to the pain. He finally gets a chance to find who his captives are and so he's ready to face them all. Besides he's got nothing to lose. Also the guys he's facing aren't really organized criminals. If anything, his slip-ups and missed punches add to the realism of the fight.

Comment: Yeah I think his sloppiness is on purpose.  He has no experience with fighting a mass like this, and is exhausted.  Purpose is all that holds him together.